# Можно ли использовать свои шрифты в xml?

Tags: android, шрифты

Я добавил в приложение несколько шрифтов, например `open-sans-semibold`. Создал папку assets и дальше туда закинул шрифты в .ttf. Можно ли сетить шрифты не программно а в xml. Некоторые вью элементы у меня не используются из активности и честно говоря не вижу смысла доставать их программно через id и давать им шрифт так:

```
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf");
txt_name.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

можно ли это сделать из xml?

Comment: посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472953/how-to-set-custom-font-in-xml-file-instead-of-java-file , вроде возможно, на сколько я понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В АПИ 26 появился атрибут `android:fontFamily`.

Создать шрифт в ресурсах:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/myfont" />
</font-family>
```

И применить:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"/>
```

[Ссылка](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml).

Comment: а нельзя как-то из папки созданной подключить?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Просто положите ттф файл в папку res/font, например, и дальше как в примере.

Comment: у меня сейчас есть папка res/assets/fonts куда я забросил шрифты, отсюда я смог подключить шрифт программно, и я думал может можно подключить их из этой папки

Comment: оффтоп: скопировал код из ответа что я кидал выше)

Comment: @Insider Из какого ответа? Это код из официальной документации.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Похоже, что из подпапки ресурс не подключить. Поигрался сейчас, не смог.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо что хоть как-то помогли :)